# Can I perform mathematical calculations on picklist values in a formula field?

Tags: formula, picklist, formula-field

I have Three fields 
one is multipicklist(type of room - A/c, non a/c, icu) and 
another one is picklist(price - 1000, 2000, 3000) and 
Total Amount

type of room and price are dependent fields
(Ex: if i select a/c, the price has to be 2000 etc.,)

My question is :

I need a formula for `(Total amount = type of room * price)`

When i use like this is giving the error as

> Error: Field Price__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only
>   supported in certain function

Comment: Hi Mohan, welcome to Salesforce Stackexchange!

Answer (score 6):

In order to get a number out of your pick list value you need to use a few functions.  The `TEXT()` function will pull the number from your pick list in text format, and then use the `VALUE()` function to convert that to a number

```
VALUE(TEXT(Field_Price__c))
```

If your other fields are also pick lists, you will need to use this method as well.